# Replace String with font with Normal text font

Tags: java, android, string, firebase, fonts

Hi I'm using Firebase Database in my app to store text of my users only . I give the possibility to my users to research text by Key-word like "Panam Palmer" . The problem is when the text is wrote with font like this ' ' the database is unable to find the post who contains the text . So my Question is how can I replace ' ' string text with 'Panam Palmer' normal text to store it in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If   is actually a font then it should work as intended as P should be 0x50 for example. However, by pasting   in a hex editor, you can see that what you posted is utf32. So, you either have to change the formatting in the database to be the same as the input or you have to parse the utf32 to whatever the input format is expecting in your database, for example, utf8. This would be done via switch or method.

Edit: Here is a sample of how I would convert it. It converts upper and lower case for those characters.

```
static String utf32ToUtf8(String input)
{
    byte[] arr = input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
    
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 53 && arr[i + 1] == -40)
        {
            i += 2;
            if (i < arr.length)
            {
                if (arr[i] >= 60 && arr[i] <= 85)
                    out.append((char) (arr[i] + 5));
                else if (arr[i] >= 86 && arr[i] <= 111)
                    out.append((char) (arr[i] + 11));
            }
        }
        else
            out.append((char)arr[i]);
    }
    return out.toString();
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "\uD835\uDE4B\uD835\uDE56\uD835\uDE63\uD835\uDE56\uD835\uDE62 \uD835\uDE4B\uD835\uDE56\uD835\uDE61\uD835\uDE62\uD835\uDE5A\uD835\uDE67";
    
    System.out.println(utf32ToUtf8(input));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the import java.text.Normalizer

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "\uD835\uDE4B\uD835\uDE56\uD835\uDE63\uD835\uDE56\uD835\uDE62 \uD835\uDE4B\uD835\uDE56\uD835\uDE61\uD835\uDE62\uD835\uDE5A\uD835\uDE67>\\n.\\n.\\n.\\n.\\n.\\n.\\n.\\n.\\n.\\n.\\n#cyberpunk #cyberpunk2077 \uD835\uDC07\uD835\uDC04\uD835\uDC08\uD835\uDC0B\uD835\uDC0D\uD835\uDC00\uD835\uDC0D";

    String ns = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFKC);
    byte[] arr = ns.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
    System.out.println(ns);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer , can you gie me the hex method to change the string " " in  "Panam Palmer"  , thanks you for your help and your time

Comment: Well Its near sir the problem is that your function is removing all the text from the string in the database . My string  in the database  is like ' >\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n#cyberpunk #cyberpunk2077 #cyberpunk2077edit #cyberpunk2077cosplay #cyberpunk2077game #cyberpunkpanam'  I need to keep everything inside of it and just change the ' '  in 'Panam Palmer' to give my user the possibility to query my database . How can I use your function  change the text  like  ' ' in'Panam Palmer'  and keep the rest of the string to.

Comment: Sorry need to repopen this case because your function doesnt work with font like '' it should give the result 'heilnan' but the result string is empty , I really need to get the normal text from every font possible @Darky

Comment: Thanks you Sir for your patience and your time working perfetcly have a nice day